# Calling MySql Function in C# for validating username and password

Tags: c#, mysql, function, authentication

Development Environment:
Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate,
C#,
MySql

Hi, I've create a function in mysql which accept 3 parameter to validate username and password.

```
DELIMITER $$

USE `generalledger`$$

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `fLogin_Check`$$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` 
FUNCTION `fLogin_Check`
(mUserName   VARCHAR(50),mUserPass VARCHAR(40),mUserKey VARCHAR(40)) RETURNS INT
BEGIN
DECLARE mCount INT;

SELECT COUNT(*) INTO mCount FROM userMaster    
WHERE userName = mUserName
AND AES_DECRYPT(userPass, mUserKey) = UPPER( mUserPass);

IF mCount > 0 THEN
RETURN 1;
ELSE
RETURN  0;
END IF;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

As you can see I am using AES_DECRYPT function of MySql to check password, because I've use AES_ENCRYPT for password when INSERT username and password to mysql table.

Now I need to call the function fLogin_Check in C#, which I am doing by using following class method:

```
public int CheckUser(string mUserName, string mPass, string mKey)
{
    oCn = da.GetConnection();

    int res;

    if (oCn == null)
    {
        oCn.Open();
    }

    sInsProcName = "fLogin_Check";
    insertcommand = new MySqlCommand(sInsProcName, oCn);
    insertcommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    insertcommand.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("mRes", MySqlDbType.Int32, 0));
    insertcommand.Parameters["mRes"].Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
    insertcommand.Parameters.Add("mUserName", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 50, mUserName);
    insertcommand.Parameters.Add("mUserPass", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 40, mPass);
    insertcommand.Parameters.Add("mUserKey", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 40);
    insertcommand.Parameters["mUserKey"].Value = mKey;

    res = insertcommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    //res = int.Parse(insertcommand.Parameters["mRes"].Value.ToString());

    return (res);

    oCn.Close();
}
```

oCn is the connection abject which uses to call GetConnection method define in my DAL class and da is the object created from DAL class, use to opening and closing database connection.

Using following Global class I am storing username and password after user enter them, and then try to validating with fLogic_Check Mysql function:

```
public static class Globals
{
    public static string userName;
    public static string userPass;
    public const string sKey = "AHMEDFINANCEICMAP1122";
}
```

sKey is the key I use to encrypt password when insert username. Now I am trying to use it in C# from Login Form when user enter Username and Password and click login button with following code:

```
private void btnCheck_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Globals.userName = txtUser.Text.ToString();
    Globals.userPass = txtPass.Text.ToString();

    if (fUser.CheckUser(Globals.userName, Globals.userPass, Globals.sKey) == 0)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Invalid Username or Password.");
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Login Successfull");
    }
}
```

It always return 0, means failed login. I've checked the Mysql function in MySql GUI and it works fine:

```
SELECT fLogin_Check("AHMED","AHMED1981","AHMEDFINANCEICMAP1122") FROM userMaster
```

which successfully return 1, however it fails when calling in C#. I've also tried to access Parameter which I've comment out after failure...What am I doing wrong?

Ahmed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code has multiple issues.

First and most important: it's better to store passwords with hash functions instead of reversible cryptographyc methods, otherwise you loose the benefits of encrypting them. I'm not going to explain this more in deep because it's been widely discussed, even here on stackoverflow. Do some research.

Second, "ExecuteNonQuery" won't return you the query output. It is used with INSERT's and UPDATE queries. You need to use "ExecuteReader" and then use the object returned to extract the row data.

Finally, your "oCn.Close();" will never be executed since there is a "return" before that line (obiviously that's not the problem but hey!).

Now, since you need the first value of the first row, there is a better function that suits your needs: ExecuteScalar. You can find more information about it on MSDN.

Comment: thanks for your answer...I've changed my code accordingly as far as ExecuteScalar is concern and it is working now!!!...I will do the research on topic Salting and Hashing and will change my code after understanding it...if you can share any sample/example link it will be helpful. Thanks

Comment: There is a beautiful article here https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm and here http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/425150/Beginners-guide-to-a-secure-way-of-storing-passwor

Comment: Thanks a lot...I will now busy myself to study it...and also try to implement it